# Can all the elements be fetched from the external system in the !same! API call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api

I have a Marketing Cloud Journey to be triggered via API for real time email sends when the customer make a specific action. At the same time, on the email that will be send via the API Journey, there must be elements included in the API call, for example a personalized URL to be send in the email to the corresponding Contact.
Ι need additional personalization data for email  and based on an older answer they wrote to me whatever it needs pass it in the API call as a separate attribute/payload .

My question is , if we proceed with this option, we can have the attributes to be used in the email within the initial API call that will trigger the Journey ? This only mean that within the API call pointing to the Journey Entry Source endpoint, a separate payload should be included so that we can fetch those data and trigger the Journey via the same API call ? If this is the case and we fetch those data in the same API call, how do we add those attributes in the email used in the API Journey?

Answer (score 1):

SFMC REST API calls only have a single function -- hence the variety of endpoints available for interacting.

If you need additional personalization data for your email, you'll need to:

1. pass it in the API call as a separate attribute/payload or
2. use a separate call in your integration for the supplemental data.

The first option way more common, due to the latency involved in having one API call being dependent on a second.

Comment: So this mean that, if we proceed with the 1st option, we can have the attributes to be used in the email within the initial API call that will trigger the Journey if I have not misunderstood. To make things clear, this only mean that within the API call pointing to the Journey Entry Source endpoint, a separate payload should be included so that we can fetch those data and trigger the Journey via the same API call? 

If this is the case and we fetch those data in the same API call, how do we add those attributes in the email used in the API Journey?